# How to access Ethernet frame in Linux kernel driver (stmmac)

Tags: linux-kernel, ethernet, raw-ethernet, ethernet-phy

For an Ethernet traffic, in the kernel `stmmac` driver, when an Ethernet frame is received, the function `stmmac_rx` is called [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.71/source/drivers/net/ethernet/stmicro/stmmac/stmmac_main.c#L2172):

```
static int stmmac_rx(struct stmmac_priv *priv, int limit)
```

I would like to access the content of each frame in the kernel. How can I access the frame content?

Comment: You want to access the content of each frame from withing `stmmac` driver's code? So you're going to modify it? Or you just want to access it from your own module?

Comment: Looks like the packet is in `skb` after `dma_unmap_single`.

Comment: @red0ct, to be honest, I'm interested for both. First, I would like to see the traffic in that function. Then I will want to process so it could be hacking into that file or doing more cleanly in a separate module.

Comment: @stark. Thank you. This is useful